# Find row with nearest value in a subset of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,5,8,103,105,112],
                   'date': pd.DatetimeIndex(('2022-02-01', '2022-02-03', '2022-02-06',
                                             '2022-02-05', '2022-02-05', '2022-02-07'))})
```

```
     x         dt
0    1 2022-02-01
1    5 2022-02-03
2    8 2022-02-06
3  103 2022-02-05
4  105 2022-02-05
5  112 2022-02-07
```

**How can I add a new column `y` that contains `x` if `x < 100` and otherwise *the x-value of the row with the next smaller date, from the subset where x < 100***.

What I currently have is this code. It works, but doesn't look very efficient:

```
df['y'] = df.x
df_ref = df.loc[df.x < 100].sort_values('date').copy()
df_ref.set_index('x', inplace=True)
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.x >= 100:
        delta = row.date - df_ref.date
        delta_gt = delta.loc[delta > pd.Timedelta(0)]
        if delta_gt.size > 0:
            df.loc[ix, 'y'] = delta_gt.idxmin()
```

```
     x       date  y
0    1 2022-02-01  1
1    5 2022-02-03  5
2    8 2022-02-06  8
3  103 2022-02-04  5
4  105 2022-02-05  5
5  112 2022-02-07  8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by date, mask the values greater than 100 and `ffill`, sort by index again:

```
(df.sort_values(by='date')
   .assign(y=df['x'].mask(df['x'].gt(100)))
   .assign(y=lambda d: d['y'].ffill())
   .sort_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
     x       date  y
0    1 2022-02-01  1
1    5 2022-02-03  5
2    8 2022-02-06  8
3  103 2022-02-05  5
4  105 2022-02-05  5
5  112 2022-02-07  8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can check `merge_asof`

```
#df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.sort_values('date')
out = pd.merge_asof(df,
                    df[df['x']<100].rename(columns={'x':'y'}),
                    on = 'date',
                    direction = 'backward').sort_values('x')
out
Out[160]: 
     x       date  y
0    1 2022-02-01  1
1    5 2022-02-03  5
4    8 2022-02-06  8
2  103 2022-02-05  5
3  105 2022-02-05  5
5  112 2022-02-07  8
```

Comment: Advantage of this solution is that instead of `direction='backward'`, neighbors in both direction could be returned by setting `direction='nearest'`